# special form for a many2many relation

Tags: python, django

with a simple model like this :

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)

class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('User')
```

Playing with tabularinline or filter_horizontal, I can for one user select severals things or for one things select multiple users, that's ok. Now I need a form like a table with checkboxes, where an admin can for many users checks many things:

```
User        Thing.name1    Thing.name2    Thing.name3 ...
User.email1      X              X
USer.email2                     X              X
...
```

I don't find a way to do this form. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Is this for the admin, or for a custom app? You won't be able to do this natively in the admin afaik

Comment: I can switch the admins to a form where auth is required